# Changing IBOutlet from seperate class not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutlet

```
-(void)buttonTapped {
    ExpandableCell * mvc= [[ExpandableCell alloc] init];
    if (mvc == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExpandingCell" owner:self options:nil];
        mvc = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
mvc.interactLabel.text = @"Second";
}
```

Isn't working for me. The interactLabel text doesn't change when compiled. This method is called when the user taps on a button in a custom cell. I've been able to change other labels in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but for some reason it won't change here. I know this method gets called because I've logged it. Could someone please help? Am I creating the ExpandableCell instance incorrectly?

Comment: in this method, you new a cell and set the label text, but you didn't use this cell...

Comment: `ExpandableCell * mvc= [[ExpandableCell alloc] init];` does `mvc` not nil. So, your if-condition never happens.

Comment: Is there any other way I can access the interactLabel and change it's text from that method @Chancy?

Comment: your button is the subview of the cell?

Comment: @Chancy no. It's just a button on a .xib which I linked an `IBOutlet` to via the `ExpandingCell` class.

Comment: you should try to use the exist cell to update the text, not new one. since don't know button and cell relation, so you should try by yourself

Comment: It looks like mvc will be nil after you out from -(void)buttonTapped method. Your if statement will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code:

```
ExpandableCell * mvc= [[ExpandableCell alloc] init];
    if (mvc == nil) {
```

Because it creates an empty view not associated with any XIB (so no sub views exist). Just keep the NIB loading code and the configuration.

After that, your code doesn't do anything with `mvc` (I assume this is just for the question and you are adding it as a subview somewhere in your real code).